# what is the correct way to include license information on an element within a microformated block of xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, licensing, microformats

Seems like rel-license only applies to pages not to specific elements... anyone spotted usage for page elements in the wild?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here and see if this is along the lines of what you're needing...

[Microsoftmats rel-license information](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-license)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `rel-license` doesn't cover specific elements is a known bug.

The following is specifically marked as an open issue on the [master list of `rel-license` issues](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-license-issues#Issues):

> 2006-04-07 raised by Evan:
>     It's not clear how to associate a license with part of a page, such as an image or embedded object in the page, or a single news entry on a news page. A typical use-case would be a Flickr page, for which the image is licensed under a CC license but the page itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally run into a situation that required this yet, but would be inclined to do something like this:

```
<p id="someparagraph">Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<div about="#someparagraph">
<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" rel="license">cc by 2.0</a>
</div>
```